# Error "Conflict resolver rejects mutation." when Delete in Amplify

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

I have a simple full-stack amplify app.

Here is my model:

```
type Note @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  image: String
  NoteType: NoteType @connection
}

type NoteType @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

I'm trying to delete a Note with the following payload:

```json
{
    "query": "mutation DeleteNote($input: DeleteNoteInput!, $condition: ModelNoteConditionInput) {↵  deleteNote(input: $input, condition: $condition) {↵    id↵    name↵    description↵    image↵    createdAt↵    updatedAt↵    NoteType {↵      id↵      name↵      createdAt↵      updatedAt↵    }↵  }↵}↵",
    "variables": {"input": {"id": "0c5e3ced-ffa3-4de8-9010-40b67d5bab68"}}
}
```

What I see in the response is the following json:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "deleteNote": null
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "path": [
                "deleteNote"
            ],
            "data": {
                "id": "0c5e3ced-ffa3-4de8-9010-40b67d5bab68",
                "name": "bb",
                "description": "bb",
                "image": "icon.png",
                "createdAt": "2020-12-21T12:00:26.743Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-12-21T12:00:26.743Z"
            },
            "errorType": "ConflictUnhandled",
            "errorInfo": null,
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 88,
                    "sourceName": null
                }
            ],
            "message": "Conflict resolver rejects mutation."
        }
    ]
}
```

The code was working until I tried to add the `NoteType`! Is there any conflict regarding the foreign-key here?

Comment: After 24 hours, now the same code makes no error and I can delete items. Somehow strange for me. I don't know what can be the reason!?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When using ConflictResolution you also need to include the _version field.

```
{
    "query": "mutation DeleteNote($input: DeleteNoteInput!, $condition: ModelNoteConditionInput) {↵  deleteNote(input: $input, condition: $condition) {↵    id↵    name↵    description↵    image↵    createdAt↵    updatedAt↵    NoteType {↵      id↵      name↵      createdAt↵      updatedAt↵    }↵  }↵}↵",
    "variables": {"input": {"id": "0c5e3ced-ffa3-4de8-9010-40b67d5bab68", "_version": "_version value of your note object"}}
}
```

I also noticed that after deleting elements that are using ConflictResolution, they are not immediately deleted from the database. Instead, two flags are being added: `_deleted` is set to true and `_ttl` is set to expire the object in 30 days.

Comment: Just be carefull when adding {"_version": the value here should be without quotation marks} since it is an integer.